# Default filter in admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there a way of setting the default value for a filter in the admin 
site?

```
Class Account(models.model): 
    isClosed = models.BooleanField(blank=True) 
    name = models.CharField(core=True, max_length=255,unique=True)
```

In admin.py:

```
class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
     list_filter = ['isClosed']
```

On the admin page, I want the default value for the 'isClosed' field 
to be 'no', not 'All'.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem with the answer, when you press show all when you don't want to apply the filter, it still apply the filter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd need to create a custom list filter, inheriting from `django.contrib.admin.filters.SimpleListFilter` and filtering on unclosed accounts by default. Something along these lines should work:

```
from datetime import date

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter


class IsClosedFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Closed')

    parameter_name = 'closed'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            (None, _('No')),
            ('yes', _('Yes')),
            ('all', _('All')),
        )

    def choices(self, cl):
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                'selected': self.value() == lookup,
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                    self.parameter_name: lookup,
                }, []),
                'display': title,
            }

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'closed':
            return queryset.filter(isClosed=True)
        elif self.value() is None:
            return queryset.filter(isClosed=False)


class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [isClosedFilter]
```

Comment: Great solution. I'll addon. That if you're using this with other list filters you'll want to do the following: `list_filter = ((isClosedFilter), ('date_created', admin.DateFieldListFilter),)`